# I need help to run React native app from Git Hub on windows

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

I need help to run this React native app on my mobile phone. https://github.com/minhtc/audiobookapp
Expo Go is installed on my android phone.
when I run the command below :

- npm install
- npx react-native run-android

here is what i get.
Can you help me please ?

```
D:\GIT Hub\audiobookapp>npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
51 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 48 up-to-date
D:\GIT Hub\audiobookapp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2] C:\Users\olinga\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\766c9672dfddf764e285b6ee68a73930\jetified-react-native-0.64.2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2] C:\Users\olinga\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\766c9672dfddf764e285b6ee68a73930\jetified-react-native-0.64.2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 37s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
D:\GIT Hub\audiobookapp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2] C:\Users\olinga\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\766c9672dfddf764e285b6ee68a73930\jetified-react-native-0.64.2\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think a library in your project uses the minSdkVersion of 21. and your project minSdkVersion is 16.
And incompatibility between these versions make this issue.

I think if you increase the project minSdkVersion to 21 the problem solved.
For this, open the root Gradle file in android root directory and in this section change 16 to 21:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        minSdkVersion = 16 --> minSdkVersion = 21
        ...
    }
}
```